# Eclipse forgetting "Save required dirty editors before launching" setting

Tags: eclipse

I have set this setting to "Prompt" many times in Run/Debug > Launching. It keeps getting set back to "Never", particularly when launching unit tests. Not every time, but every few weeks.

Is it because Eclipse creates a new Debug configuration for each test class? Is it creating them from a template somewhere that I can change? All of my other Eclipse settings stay the way I set them.

Comment: This preference is per workspace and not per run configuration. Is _Window > Preferences: Oomph > Setup Tasks > Preference Recorder_ enabled? Which Eclipse version do you use? Do you have any other plug-ins installed?

Comment: @howlger It is not enabled. Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a). TestNG, SonarLint, HtmlEditor(WTP), SQL Dev Tools 1.14. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: You are two releases behind: Oxygen -> Photon -> 2018-09. Please upgrade. The TestNG plugin might have something to do with it. So make sure the TestNG plugin is also up to date. If you can reproduce this issue with 2018-09, please report it to Eclipse (if it can be reproduced even without the TestNG plugin) or to the TestNG plugin project (otherwise).

Comment: Happens to me too, in all versions (currently Photon.)